# How to Bypass Data Layer Using Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I'm learning to test my controllers using Moq, but I'm unsure of how I should bypass the data layer calls from my controller. Say I have a method like below.  What approach would I take to test a simple controller like such?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeController(SomeModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Perform some manipulation on modeldata
        model.Value++;

        // Upload Model, Get ID
        model.Id = MyDataLayer.UploadToDb(model);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You need to abstract away your data layer using an interface.  And inject the implementation of the data layer in the contstructor of your Controller.  The implementation can then be either the moq'd version or the actual implementation

Comment: To quote HotFuzz (points to @KiwiPiet): "What he said".

Comment: Is `MyDataLayer` static or a local variable in the example provided?

Comment: @Nkosi `MyDataLayer` would be a static function from a class library .dll

Comment: @lloyd OK, then follow the answer already given to refactor your code to make it more unit-test friendly. Having static dependencies make your code difficult to test in isolation. Once you decouple your code from the static dependency you are now free to mock up the dependencies for easier unit testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
interface IMyDataLayer 
{
    int UploadToDb(SomeModel model);
}
class MyDataLayer : IMyDataLayer 
{
    public int UploadToDb(SomeModel model)
    {
        // Implementation ...
    }
}
class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyDataLayer _datalayer;
    public MyController(IMyDataLayer datalayer)
    {
        _datalayer = _datalayer;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Perform some manipulation on modeldata
            model.Value++;

            // Upload Model, Get ID
            model.Id = _datalayer.UploadToDb(model);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then you can use Moq to create a mock of IMyDataLayer.

Comment: Show an example of creating the mock and injecting it into the SUT

Comment: Ok just thought it would help the OP. they asked how to do it using MOQ didn't they? What you have done is showed how they can refactor their code to allow for dependency injection, not necessarily how to do it with MOQ

Answer (score 1):

I implemented KiwiPet's solution using moq like the following.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // Create test input data
    SomeModel TestModel = new SomeModel();
    TestModel.Value = 1;

    // Create mocked data layer
    var FakeDataLayer = new Mock<IMyDataLayer>();
    FakeDataLayer.Setup(x => x.UploadToDb(It.IsAny<SomeModel>()).Returns(TestValueIWantReturned);

    // Create controller using fake data service
    var controller = new MyController(FakeDataLayer.Object);

    // Controller function call
    var result = controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;

    // Assert stuff
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.Model);
    // ...

}
```